# What is difference between external and internal css?

Tags: css

I watched a flex tutorial and I found parts mentionning external and internal css. So what is the differences between the two ?

Comment: EDIT - seems like the comment I was replying to has been deleted. Hmm, I have to disagree, `inline css` would be directly adding the css to inline elements. `<div style="width:960px; margin:0 auto">` this would be an example of `inline css`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`External` CSS refers to a file location, ie

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="your-file-here.css">
```

`Internal` CSS

Means that the CSS is included on the page, wrapped in `style` tags in the `<head>`:

So:

```
<style>
    #wrapper { width:960px; margin:0 auto; }
</style>
```

When internally using CSS, styles can be used in what is called inline styles.

Which looks like:

```
<p style="color: #333; font-size: 22px;">Blah blah blah.</p>
```

The only real benefit to `internal` CSS, is that the browser doesn't need to make an additional `GET` request to download the `.css` file. But `external` is preffered. As it means you just need to modify the `.css` file, and it will be reflected in all pages which include a reference to that specific file.

Answer (score 2):

### Internal CSS

- Defined inside `<style>` elements.
- Embedded directly inside the page.

### External CSS

- Linked via the `<link rel="stylesheet">` element.
- Exists as a seperate file on the server.

The main advantage of an external CSS file, is that it can be cached independently from pages, meaning that the client only needs to download it once, which saves on loading times and bandwidth.

Also, by linking many pages to once CSS file, you only need to change one place, and have all of the site immediately affected (without having to go on every page and make the change).

Answer (score 2):

An internal style sheet is a `style` tag in the `head` section of the page:

```
<style type="text/css">

body { margin: 0; padding; 10px; }

</style>
```

An external style sheet is a CSS file that is used by the page from a `link` tag in the `head` section:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="pagestyles.css" />
```

An external style sheet can also be specificed using the [`@import`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@import) CSS rule, either from an internal style sheet or another external style sheet:

```
@import "otherstyles.css";
```

There is also a third type of css; inline styles that are specified on the element that they apply to:

```
<div style="background:#ccc;">
```